# irssi tries to join #python before sending the identify message

Tags: irc, irssi

I am starting off with irssi here and have a small setup trying to connect to a few channels on freenode. I have the following in my `chatnets` directive in my `.irssi/config`

```
Freenode = {
  type = "IRC";
  autosendcmd = "/^msg NickServ IDENTIFY <password>; wait 2000";
};
```

and the following is the channels directive

```
channels = (
  { name = "#vim"; chatnet = "Freenode"; autojoin = "Yes"; },
  { name = "#jquery"; chatnet = "Freenode"; autojoin = "Yes"; },
  { name = "#python"; chatnet = "Freenode"; autojoin = "Yes"; },
  { name = "#coffeescript"; chatnet = "Freenode"; autojoin = "Yes"; },
  { name = "#clojure"; chatnet = "Freenode"; autojoin = "Yes"; }
);
```

Now, when I open irssi, I expect to see all the above channels open and ready. All channels work that way except for `#python` which gets redirected to `#python-unregistered` and asks me to identify myself. I'd like irssi to wait until the identification is finished before it joins the channels. I hoped that the `wait 2000` would do this, but apparently not.

Am I missing something? I am a beginner with irssi so have little idea. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Set your nick password as the server password. Freenode's IRCd accepts the server password and will attempt to identify with it.

Comment: Awesome. I saw the docs and added a new server(freenode2) and saw how it was setting the password in the config and added that password to my config, as a `password=` directive. It works now. Thank you Ignacio :)

Comment: I guess this only works if your nick and the nick you want to register to are the same. Unfortunately for me they differ. The wait trick seems to work, but only with *6000* instead of *2000*.

Comment: @scai: You can send it as `user:pass` :-)

Answer (score 6):

The commands are (example: irc.freenode.net):

Remove current setting first

```
/server list
/server remove irc.freenode.net
```

Add server

```
/SERVER ADD -auto -network Freenode irc.freenode.net 6667 your_nick_password
```

Now add your channel(s)

```
/channel add -auto #fedora Freenode
```

Save your changes

```
/save
```

Comment: Instead of re-adding the server you can also add `password = "foobar";` in your `.irssi/config` file.

Comment: @nuala, while true, the IRSSI ideology is to avoid manual editing of the configuration file. So, readding server is a proper thing to do.